# Calculate time difference beetween two dates with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have two dates in format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

How I can calculate time beetweeb two dates:

```
data.endTime - data.startTime
```

Comment: Convert them to _Date_, subtract them, the difference will be in _ms_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is like @Paul S. say, convert them into Date, and then yo can make something like this:

```
var resultInMs = date_end.getTime() - date_start.getTime();
```

Hope it works for you.

PD: Here is something that can help you http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

PD2: Like @James Thorpe says Mozilla Docs is also a very good source of information (Even better): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: fyi, the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) are typically far better than w3schools

Comment: You can also use integer conversion, i.e. `var resultMs = (+date_end) - (+date_start)`